# Как разделить несколько строк в одном столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Не получается отделить первые строки от столбца, как будто они заменяют индекс строк.

Моя цель избавиться в столбце от строчек с датами, и оставить только строки с числами, но разделитель игнорирует условие:

[Данные CSV](https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv?req=%7B%22time%22%3A%222016-12-11%202020-12-11%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%22WEEK%22%2C%22locale%22%3A%22en-GB%22%2C%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22geo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22complexKeywordsRestriction%22%3A%7B%22keyword%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22ENTITY%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2Fm%2F0rphppq%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22requestOptions%22%3A%7B%22property%22%3A%22%22%2C%22backend%22%3A%22IZG%22%2C%22category%22%3A0%7D%7D&token=APP6_UEAAAAAX-RGqySljbhYLa6Jrtw-c6wHAUeK3908&tz=-240)

```
import pandas as pd
fp='C:/Users/CodeMaker/Downloads/multiTimeline.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(fp)
new = data['Category: All categories'].str.split(',', n = 1, expand = True) 
data["First Name"]= new[0]
exs=data.iloc[0:900,1:4]
print(exs)
```

Comment: Из описания совершенно непонятно что вы хотите получить в итоге. Можете привести пример результата (3-5 строк)?

Comment: `pd.read_csv(fp, sep=',')` пробовали?

Comment: pd.read_csv(fp, skiprows=1) ?

Comment: @MaxU В 4 строчке пытаюсь разделить на 2 столца, оставив строки с датой в одном столбце до разделителя, а во 2 столбец оставить данные с числовыми показателями. Для этого создал второй столбец в 5 строчке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [параметром “skiprows”](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(fp, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!